# HTML + CSS horizontal ordered form elements

Tags: html, css, webforms

Given the following HTML-Code:

```
<form id="contact-form">
    <label for="form-company">Company</label>
    <input id="form-company" name="form-company" type="text">

    <label for="form-name">Name</label>
    <input id="form-name" name="form-name" type="text" required>

    <label for="form-email">Email</label>
    <input id="form-email" name="form-email" type="email" required>

    <label for="form-tel">Phone</label>
    <input id="form-tel" name="form-tel" type="tel" required>

    <label for="form-message">Message</label>
    <textarea id="form-message" name="form-message" required>
    </textarea>            

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I want to style this form with the result that it looks like the following image illustrates:
[image]

What's the best and most compatible way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? This might actually be a good candidate for a table with `border-collapse` set, although you could do it without a table of course.

Comment: +1 on @PeeHaa cause the best way to develop anything is don't make it difficult just think in a simple and easy way.

Comment: I dislike tables for anything but tables. If I can find a css solution, I prefer it. It may be more difficult to work out, but the clutter it saves in source code is usually worth the time to me.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done pretty painlessly with a series of floating divs. I've created a jsFiddle that should be pretty close to what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/xgNBv/

Answer (score 0):

**A Pure CSS Solution** that does not require any additional html markup would be like this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TBwQh/27/. This works in IE8+, and could be tweaked to work in IE7 (needs some top margin adjustment it appears), though IE7 will not show the vertical dividing dashed line.

The CSS is:

```
#contact-form {
    width: 600px;
}

#contact-form label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 176px;
    height: 1em;
    padding: 1.5em 424px 1.5em 0;
    margin-right: -412px;
    text-align: right;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #bbbbbb;
    position: relative;
}

#contact-form label:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    border-right: 1px dashed #bbbbbb;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 12px;
}

#contact-form input,
#contact-form textarea {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 376px;
    height: 3em;
    margin: .5em 12px;
    vertical-align: middle; /* textarea needed this */
}

#contact-form input[type=submit] {
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 188px;
}
```

Obviously, some adjustments could be made on the sizes. One would have to evaluate if the "complexity" of the css or the inability to get it completely the same look in IE7 and under is worth not going the table or extra div route as already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I've done it by using the `table` approach.

HTML:

```
<form id="contact-form">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="form-company">Company:</label></td>
            <td><input id="form-company" name="form-company" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="form-name">Name:</label></td>
            <td><input id="form-name" name="form-name" type="text" required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="form-email">Email:</label></td>
            <td><input id="form-email" name="form-email" type="email" required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="form-tel">Phone:</label></td>
            <td><input id="form-tel" name="form-tel" type="tel" required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="form-message">Message:</label></td>
            <td><textarea id="form-message" name="form-message" required></textarea></td>
        </tr>
    </table> 

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

CSS:

```
*          { margin:0; }
html, body { height: 100%; }

#contact-form {
    height:     100%;
    margin:     0 auto;
    width:      75%;
    text-align: center;
}

#contact-form table { margin: 0 auto; width:  100%; }

#contact-form td:nth-of-type(odd)    { width: 25%; }
#contact-form td:nth-of-type(even)   { width: 75%; }
#contact-form td:nth-of-type(odd)  * { float: right; padding-right: 10%; }
#contact-form td:nth-of-type(even) * { width: 100%; }

#contact-form table textarea { resize: none; }
#form-submit                 { width: 25%; }
```